# Adding attributes to laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i have to put some attributes to my laravel collections.

My laravel collection original attributes :

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => array:20 [▼
        "curr" => "IDR"
        "price" => 5500000.0
        "rate" => 14325.803
        "qty" => 2
    ]
    1 => array:20 [▼
        "curr" => "IDR"
        "price" => 1500000.0
        "rate" => 14325.803
        "qty" => 1
    ]
]
```

i want to add "amount" attribute which the result of multiplying "price" x "qty" like so :

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => array:20 [▼
        "curr" => "IDR"
        "price" => 5500000.0
        "rate" => 14325.803
        "qty" => 2
        "amount" => 11000000.0
    ]
    1 => array:20 [▼
        "curr" => "IDR"
        "price" => 1500000.0
        "rate" => 14325.803
        "qty" => 1
        "amount" => 1500000.0
    ]
]
```

i tried to do it by put() method of laravel collection, but it seems the each() method will remove the collection instance, so i can't use the put() method :

```
$collection->each(function($item) {
    $item->put('amount', $item->price * $item->qty);
});
```

What's the solution of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `->put` in an `->each` loop for this case, because `->each` does not loop the items by reference. So all modifications to the item are lost after the loop.

You can map the array to return your actual `$item` merged with the extra key `amount`. The correct method to use is `->map`.

```php
$collection = $collection->map(function($item) {
    return array_merge($item, [
        'amount' => $item->price * $item->qty;
    ]);
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map

Comment: wow this works as i desired, thanks a lot, but  sorry just one to make sure, is this have anything to do with performance ? do i need to chunk them first ? because the query might resulting around 20k ~ 50k rows

Comment: I’m assuming you are loading these items from a database somewhere? If so, you can use either chunk or cursor on the query and run this inside the collection loop.

Comment: @Savlon yes i load those from db, tried it with chunk got 200ms decrease, thanks !